# Update column based on weekday(datetime) (MySQL)

Tags: mysql

Hey guys pretty new to MySQL
What I would like to do to is update a column based upon whether it meets the condition of being a certain day of the week.
I know this is wrong but I feel like it would give a better idea of what I'm trying to do.

```
SELECT * FROM myschema.mytable WHERE WEEKDAY(OrderDate) BETWEEN 0 AND 0
ALTER TABLE myschema.mytable
ADD DateNumber INTEGER
UPDATE myschema.mytable SET DateNumber '1'
```

I'm sure I'm way off here, can someone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 0):

You can't update the result of a SELECT, but you can update with a where condition such as :

```
UPDATE myschema.mytable SET DateNumber='1' WHERE WEEKDAY(OrderDate) BETWEEN 0 AND 0
```

Comment: your question is not really clear. First why would you alter your table at all? Second why store redundant information? There should be no need to have a column store the information you can already get by querying the OrderDate column. What problem are you really trying to solve?

Comment: This is perfect. I really want to just be able to pull a report based on the day of the week. Eventually I want to move this data to a whole other table to cut the time of the query result. I think perhaps you are correct that there is a query that could do this also. Again though, not very experienced in MySQL, so what I'm thinking might not make much sense.

Answer (score 0):

I am guessing that this might be what you want:

```
SELECT *, CASE WEEKDAY(OrderDate) WHEN 0 THEN 1 END DateNumber FROM mytable
```

This way you don't change the actual table but add an extra (conditional) 'DateNumber' column to the output.

With a table like this

```
CREATE TABLE mytable (Id int, OrderDate datetime, SomeNumber int null);

INSERT INTO mytable (Id, OrderDate, SomeNumber) VALUES
    (1, '2016-1-7', 5),
    (2, '2016-1-8', 6),
    (3, '2016-1-9', 4),
    (4, '2016-1-10', 1),
    (5, '2016-1-11', 9),
    (6, '2016-1-12', 7);
```

You would be getting the following output:

```
| Id |                 OrderDate | SomeNumber | DateNumber |
|----|---------------------------|------------|------------|
|  1 | January, 07 2016 00:00:00 |          5 |     (null) |
|  2 | January, 08 2016 00:00:00 |          6 |     (null) |
|  3 | January, 09 2016 00:00:00 |          4 |     (null) |
|  4 | January, 10 2016 00:00:00 |          1 |     (null) |
|  5 | January, 11 2016 00:00:00 |          9 |          1 |
|  6 | January, 12 2016 00:00:00 |          7 |     (null) |
```

see here: [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/72f5d/1)